# Other than player death, is there any other way for Assault to lose tickets?

Tags: battlefield-bad-company-2

In Battlefield Bad Company 2 Multiplayer Rush, is there any other way for the Assault team to lose tickets other than when teammates die?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of for the attack team.